# Userdefined search, searching through a txt-file

Tags: java, input

I'm having some problems. I have a *txt-file that I'm reading into the program (PART A). That works just fine, and so does using the scanner to search for the word/name "Winnie-the-Pooh" in PART B. What I'm having problems with is part C, where i want the user to choose for him/herself which word to search the *txt-file for.

It seems whatever I'm doing, the scanner returns 4 (the number of times the last word in the text appears).

Hope some of you guys could help me out with PART C.

Below is the code, and it compiles just fine.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Innlesing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String winnie;
    int antall = 0;
    int linjeNummer = 1;
    String filNavn = "winnie.txt";
    Scanner scanFil = new Scanner(new File(filNavn));

   // PART A
   while (scanFil.hasNextLine()) {
       String linje = scanFil.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Linje " + linjeNummer + ": " + linje);
       linjeNummer++;
   }

   // PART B
   Scanner soekeOrd = new Scanner(new File(filNavn));
   while (soekeOrd.hasNextLine()){
       winnie = soekeOrd.nextLine();
       if (winnie.equals("Winnie-the-Pooh")){
       antall += 1;
       }
   }

   System.out.println("Antall forekomster av Winnie-the-Pooh er: " + antall );

   // PART C
   Scanner brukerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   String brukerInput2;

   System.out.println("Hvilket ord vil du soeke paa?: ");
   brukerInput2 = brukerInput.nextLine();

   while (scanFil.hasNextLine()) {
       brukerInput2 = scanFil.nextLine();
       if (brukerInput.equals("pluskvamperfektum")) {
       antall +=1;
       }
   }
System.out.println("Antall forekomster av " + brukerInput2 + " er: " + antall );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several mistakes. Here is Part C corrected. First of all, using brukerInput.equals("pluskvamperfektum") you wanted to check if a Scanner instance equals to a String literal. You need to read a line from the file, and check if the string typed by the user is part of it - for example, it occurs at a non-negative index in it. You have also forgot to reset the counter. One more important thing in real-life programs is to close all resources when they are not needed - this time I have did it to soekeOrd2.

```
antall = 0;
Scanner soekeOrd2 = new Scanner(new File(filNavn));
Scanner brukerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String brukerInput2;

System.out.println("Hvilket ord vil du soeke paa?: ");
brukerInput2 = brukerInput.nextLine();

while (soekeOrd2.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = soekeOrd2.nextLine();
    if (line.indexOf(brukerInput2) >= 0) {
    antall +=1;
    }
}
System.out.println("Antall forekomster av " + brukerInput2 + " er: " + antall );
soekeOrd2.close()
```

best regards: Balázs

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch! Your answer was really helpful, and cleared up some serious issues for me. I wish I could vote your answer up, but I don't have enough rep.